# How to format docker API out?

Tags: image, docker, command

How we can format docker API output as we do with using docker command,
e.g.

```
docker inspect <Image id>  --format "{{json .Tag}}"
```

Command give you the list of tag of all the images available on host.

How can get this formatted information using docker API?

e.g. `http:localhost/images/<image id>/json?<something..>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker's API doesn't support any formatting. The `--format` flag is implemented only in client side. You might want to look into tools like https://stedolan.github.io/jq/ to do that formatting.